# How do I listen to "_users" with PouchDB?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

It seems like PouchDB doesn't allow me to listen to `_users` db, even if I'm logged in as admin.

I'm using [socket-pouch](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/socket-pouch) and [pouchdb-authentication](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication) to work with PouchDB. Firstly I'm logging in with pouchdb-authentication and then trying to subscribe to specified database with socket-pouch.

It works just fine for pretty much any ordinary database, but I'm keep getting 401 error when trying to sync with `_users` database, even if I'm logged in as admin:

```
Uncaught (in promise) n {error: "unauthorized", name: "unauthorized", 
reason: "You are not a server admin.", message: "You are not a server 
admin.", status: 401, …}
```

Is it possible to sync with `_users` database with PouchDB?

The `_users` database is easily accessible via curl, so my admin credentials are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just omitted `socket-pouch` and it worked. It seems like that error is happening because of some `socket-pouch` bugs, not PouchDB itself.